# $\int \frac{1}{(\cos x)^{2n+1}}dx$

Tags: trigonometric-integrals, trigonometric-series

I am struggling to recreate the result from this article (part 3) see link (page 295):https://archive.org/details/sim_mathematics-magazine_1936-05_10_8/page/294/mode/2up

This is what I have done so far:
[My work so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44Uqq.png)

Comment: [Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34121/42969). Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. – For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: So you're just stuck on the final integral, $\displaystyle \int \sec x \, dx$ ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that $\int{\sec^{n}(\theta)}=\frac{\tan(\theta)\sec^{n-2}(\theta)}{n-1}-\frac{n-2}{n-1}\int{\sec^{n-2}(\theta)d\theta}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/463683/prove-that-int-secn-theta-frac-tan-theta-secn-2-thetan-1-f)

Comment: I want a genereal solution for said integral. 
The general solutuon can be found from this link <https://archive.org/details/sim_mathematics-magazine_1936-05_10_8/page/294/mode/2up>

I cannot seem to recreate the calculations

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is of some use:

```
Integrate[1/Cos[x]^(2*m + 1), x]

(1/(2*m))*((Csc[x]*
    Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, -m, 
     1 - m, Cos[x]^2]*
    Sqrt[Sin[x]^2])/Cos[x]^(2*m))
    
FullSimplify[Evaluate[
     Integrate[1/Cos[x]^(2*m + 1), 
       x]], Element[m, Integers]]
       
(-(1/2))*Beta[Cos[x]^2, -m, 1/2]*
  Csc[x]*Sqrt[Sin[x]^2]
``
```